# How can I actually save a credit card for later?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Stripe gives this [great example](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later) of how save a credit card and charge it later.

Except they're not actually charging a *credit card* later, they're charging a *customer* later. I want to allow my users to pick which CC on file gets charged.

The [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) hints that I should be able to create a token needed for  a charge by passing the card ID and customer ID if I'm using Stripe Connect, which I am.

So I've tried:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'))

$token = \Stripe\Token::create([
    'card' => 'card_19hSQyK4YQ3aCebXXXXXX',
    'customer' => 'cus_A1VRwawXXXXXX',
], ['stripe_account' => 'acct_15H0GKKXXXXXXXXX']);
```

But I get this error:

> Must authenticate as a connected account to be able to use customer parameter. See https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token for more details.

I'm not quite sure what that means. Should I be using *my* secret key or the secret of the client?

Comment: When you charge your customer, you should be able to add the "card_id"=>value to your array, and you can store that for later.

Comment: Also #Stripe on Freenode, lots of helpful people in there for assistance with Stripe including their Dev team.

Comment: @Kaylined To which array? `\Stripe\Charge::create`? If I try that I get "Must provide source or customer". If I add the customer too, I get "Received unknown parameter: card_id".

Comment: @Kaylined Been trying to get help on freenode for hours now.

Comment: Go on now, and ask Mattwc - he's got the knowledge you seek! When you find the answer, post it on here.

Comment: @Kaylined Just noticed Mattwc did respond. He put me in the right direction, will post it here in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to create a token if you have the card # and customer # -- just create the charge using the card # as the `source` and the customer ID as `customer`.

e.g.,

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 500,
    'currency' => 'CAD',
    'source' => 'card_19hSQyK4YQ3aCebXXXXXX',
    'customer' => 'cus_A1VRwawXXXXXX',
], ['stripe_account' => 'acct_15H0GKKXXXXXXXXX']);
```

And here's how you can get the credit cards from Stripe:

```
$creditCards = [];

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
$stripeCustomer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($booking->customer->stripe_customer_id);

$defaultSource = $stripeCustomer->default_source;

foreach($stripeCustomer->sources->all()->data as $paySource) {
    switch($paySource['object']) {
        case 'card':
            $creditCards[$paySource->id] = $paySource->brand . ' ending in ' . $paySource->last4 . ' (Exp. ' . $paySource->exp_month . '/' . $paySource->exp_year . ')';
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception("Unexpected Stripe payment source type: " . $paySource['object']);
    }
}
```